# Input string not in correct format

Tags: c#, .net, input

Hello the problem I am having can be seen in the comments below. Basically I am coming to the point where the input is in the incorrect format and i cannot see why, below is also the data i am attempting to put in.

The data,

```
128,119,137,140,128,117,197     -0.5,0.0,0.5
125,129,136,130,125,162,125     -1.0,0.0,1.0
138,139,135,120,127,117,118     -0.5,0.0,0.5
127,149,138,160,122,217,137
149,129,140,140,129,127,126
153,159,130,140,127,112,126
147,129,130,148,128,137,134
```

Can anyone see why it wont accept it?

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("c:/users/tom/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/Exam/Exam/Data.txt");     

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)   // Ignores first two lines
{
   String input =  tr.ReadLine();
}                

string remainingText = tr.ReadToEnd(); //Reads remained            
string result = Regex.Replace(remainingText, @"\s+", ",");

char[] delimiterChars = {','};        //Establishes what should split the strings
string[] itemlist = (result.Split(delimiterChars)); //Splits the strings and puts them into itemlist
double[] values = new double[itemlist.Length];        //Creates an array the same size as itemlist

for (int i = 0; i < itemlist.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] = (Convert.ToDouble(itemlist[i]));  
    //Attempts to convert the >values from itemlist into values ERROR, input string not in correct format
}
```

Comment: Please explain where you are reading this file from..? Server or Local file path on your machine..?

Comment: Edit that data into your post.

Comment: What does "it wont accept it" mean? It throws an exception? Show us the exception.

Comment: It says, "Input String was not in correct format"

Comment: Wrap values[i] = (Convert.ToDouble(itemlist[i])); in a try/catch block. In the catch block, write the failed value to console, screen, where ever you can see it. Then you can ask, why doesn't ",0.1," convert, or whatever it is. Sometimes it's the invisible EOF or line feed crud that makes data import blow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `Split`

```
string[] itemlist = (result.Split(delimiterChars,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: Oh that worked! Thannkyou